# reproduce envelope design

Tags: tikz-pgf

Not being a specialist of TikZ, I have no chance to succeed in posting a MWE to reproduce the envelope design above. Any hint to start?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You don't need to be a specialist to make a start. At least provide the basic framework of the document and the text that needs to go on the envelope. Otherwise, anybody (everybody) who wants to help has to type out the lot from scratch.

Comment: Given the amount of text I'm not really sure this is best done in `tikz` at all. Why not just use a tabular or minipages in landscape orientation. I don't see why you want an image of the envelope if you are trying to e.g. print envelopes. What you want is to layout the text which you then print onto envelopes.

Comment: @Laura Could you post the dimensions of the envelope (width and height preferably in millimeters)?

To clarify your question, is this an [envelope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope) or a [post card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcard)?

Comment: @szantaii it's an envelope suitable for A4 content. Dimensions mm 229 × 324. I'll post a MWE as soon as I can

Answer (score 5):

This code uses a series of `minipage`s to split up the design and set the proper text in the right places.

I have used `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}\usepackage[random]{blindtext}` to include some dummy text; yes, German.  `blindtext` does not support Italian, and `lipsum` doesn't provide the granularity in terms of length that I wanted.

I was able to set the size of the envelope to the dimensions you mentioned: 32.4cm x 22.9cm.  Many of the spacings in the typesetting are flexible, though, so the size is changeable with little extra work.  The most obvious difference will be the change in relative size of the fonts with a different size paper.

I selected a font ([TeX Gyre Schola](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/tgschola/)) that I thought closely resembled that in the pic, with a bit wider base and heavier type.

I even made the envelope the approximate shade of green in the picture, though that can be removed easily by commenting the lines:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{HTML}{84c384}
\pagecolor{darkgreen}
```

### Original

[image: original]

### Sample

[image: pic]

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[random]{blindtext}

\usepackage{tgschola}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{HTML}{84c384}
\pagecolor{darkgreen}
\usepackage[
    paperwidth=32.4cm,
    paperheight=22.9cm,
    margin=5mm,
    nofoot,nohead,
    ]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% Left frame
\noindent\hspace{0.5ex}
\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][t]{.28\linewidth}
\begin{center}
{\Large NOTIFICAZIONE \\[1ex] DI ATTI GIUDIZIARI}

\vspace{1ex}\footnotesize ai sensi della Legge 21/1/94, n.\ 53

\vspace{1ex}Autorizzazione Consiglio Ordine Avvocati di Roma

\vspace{1ex}N. \hspace{2cm} del

{ % Make box
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\framebox[\linewidth]{ % Set box \linewidth x 3cm
    \rule{0pt}{3.5cm}
    }
}%

\vspace{1.5cm}
{\large N. \hrulefill\ del Registro Cronologico}\\[1ex]

\emph{Firma dell'Avvocato notificante}%
\end{center}
\vfill
\hrule
\vfill
{\center\large A V V E R T E N Z E\\[1ex]}
\footnotesize\parindent=10pt

\blindtext[2]

\blindtext[4]

\blindtext[3]

\blindtext[1]

\vspace{1.5cm} % add some space on the bottom
\end{minipage}
\hspace{4ex}\hfill % Pad the next minipage on either side
% Right frame
\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][t]{.445\linewidth}
\vspace{1.7cm}
\hfill { % Make stamp box
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\framebox[2.5cm]{ % Set box 2cm x 2cm
    \rule{0pt}{2.5cm}
    }
}

\vfill
{ % Make box
\setlength{\fboxsep}{5pt}
\framebox{\rule{0pt}{1cm}%
Racc.\ N. \rule{2.5cm}{\fboxrule}}}
\vspace{2ex}

\rule{\fboxrule}{9cm}\hspace{2ex}
\newlength{\shorterbox}
\setlength{\shorterbox}{\linewidth}
\addtolength{\shorterbox}{-4ex}
\begin{minipage}[b][9cm][t]{\shorterbox}
\Large
\vfill\hrulefill\par
\vfill\hrulefill\par
\vfill\hrulefill\par
\vfill(\hrulefill)\quad\hrulefill\par
\vspace{1ex}
\end{minipage}

\hfill\tiny Really small text that no one will read
\vspace{1cm}

\end{minipage}
\hfill~ % Pad the previous minipage on either side
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) for the answer but I don't really approve! (What happened to 'I've got some code which I'll post if...'?!)